# GPU in blender rendering

Tags: rendering

can i use my amd radeon r7 265 with cycles opencl rendering in blender 2.78 b . and how to enable it ??? help me please

[image]

[image]

Comment: your second picture is the correct setting. then in the properties panel go to the render tab and set the *Device* to GPU

Comment: when i set it like you said it take a long time to render then cpu can you help with that please ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMD radeon r7 265 is on the list of supported devices: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/OpenCL

There are two settings you need to change to enable GPU rendering.  The first is in User Preferences like you show, and the second is in the rendering tab of the properties panel.

[image]
[image]

Increase tile size for better GPU performance with non-progressive rendering.

[image]

Comment: did the name of the card must shown in the list in user preference ? because in my case is not . and should i select glsl compute like you show ?

Comment: @RoMax, I believe he's using a different version than you.  Do you now have the option in the drop-down menu to use GPU compute (picture on the right)?  If so then Blender is using your card.  Oland is a type of architecture.

Comment: @bertmoog . yes i have it and i set it to gpu compute but when i render it take aloooooong time then cpu  ? can you help with that please ?

Comment: For non-progressive rendering make sure your tile-size is set to something high like 256. But it's also possible your CPU is actually faster for cycles than your GPU.  Not every graphics card offers a significant speedup.

Comment: @RoMax With that video card, you won't see a large boost if any at all.  I had a HD 6870 which is only about 20% slower than the R7 265 and my FX-8320 CPU would smoke it.  But, as Lukas said, tile size is key.  Keep the tile as close to 256x256 as possible.